# CLion doesn't sort include statements on commit

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, ide, clion, clang-format

I'm using clang-format to define rules for sorting my include statements. This works perfectly when using the "Code > Reformat Code" button or pressing `CTRL + ALT + L` within a file.

However, **even when setting the "Reformat code" checkbox in the CLion commit dialog, the include statements don't get sorted when commiting.** For some reason other formatting tasks (such as fixing indentation) take place when commiting. It's just the include sorting that's missing.

Does anybody know why that is the case? Many thanks!

From the `.clang-format` file:

```
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority: 1
  - Regex: '^<[^.]*>'
    Priority: 2
  - Regex: '<.*>'
    Priority: 3
  - Regex: '.*'
    Priority: 3
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
SortIncludes: true
```

[image: Commit Dialog]

[image: Format Settings]

Comment: Isn't this reformat only changed part of code? Just to prevent extensive diff.

Comment: @MarekR Could be the case. But I've explicitly moved one include statement to the "wrong place", then hit Commit and it remained in the wrong place. Pressing CTRL + ALT + L moved it back into the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains Support confirmed to be that this is a bug within CLion that they managed to reproduce on their system.

Hoping for it to be fixed in a future version :)

Comment: The main reason for this is that the operation is risky.
Code may become uncompileable after reordering. Seems like the commit action is not the best place for things like this.